# Phoenix crate a RESTful API, error message: no function clause matching

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am learning how to use Phoenix to create RESTful API. My steps as follows:

step1: use mix task create database schema and some code

```
mix phx.gen.context AnimalAdmin Animal animal name:string email:string:unique role:string address:string

mix phx.gen.json AnimalAdmin Animal animal name:string email:string:unique role:string address:string --no-context --no-schema
```

step2: update my repository by running

```
mix ecto.migrate
```

step3: update router.ex file

```
pipe_through :api
get "/animal", AnimalController, :index
put "/animal", AnimalController, :edit
post "/animal", AnimalController, :create
delete "/animal", AnimalController, :delete
```

step4: start server

```
mix phx.server
```

The animal_controller.ex file is

```
defmodule InvestmentBackWeb.AnimalController do
  use InvestmentBackWeb, :controller

  alias InvestmentBack.AnimalAdmin
  alias InvestmentBack.AnimalAdmin.Animal

  action_fallback InvestmentBackWeb.FallbackController

  def index(conn, _params) do
    animal = AnimalAdmin.list_animal()
    render(conn, "index.json", animal: animal)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"animal" => animal_params}) do
    with {:ok, %Animal{} = animal} <- AnimalAdmin.create_animal(animal_params) do
      conn
      |> put_status(:created)
      # |> put_resp_header("location", Routes.animal_path(conn, :show, animal))
      |> render("show.json", animal: animal)
    end
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    animal = AnimalAdmin.get_animal!(id)
    render(conn, "show.json", animal: animal)
  end

  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "animal" => animal_params}) do
    animal = AnimalAdmin.get_animal!(id)

    with {:ok, %Animal{} = animal} <- AnimalAdmin.update_animal(animal, animal_params) do
      render(conn, "show.json", animal: animal)
    end
  end

  def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    animal = AnimalAdmin.get_animal!(id)

    with {:ok, %Animal{}} <- AnimalAdmin.delete_animal(animal) do
      send_resp(conn, :no_content, "")
    end
  end
end
```

I want add a row data to my repository by phoenix RESTful API, and use postman as this

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR7Ga.jpg)

When send a HTTP request, the response' code is 400, and error message is :

```
no function clause matching in InvestmentBackWeb.AnimalController.create/2

The following arguments were given to InvestmentBackWeb.AnimalController.create/2:

    # 1
    %Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{}, body_params: %{"address" => "china", "email" => "smallstul@gmail.com", "name" => "xingxingliu", "role" => "new developer"}, cookies: %{}, halted: false, host: "localhost", method: "POST", owner: #PID<0.555.0>, params: %{"address" => "china", "email" => "smallstul@gmail.com", "name" => "xingxingliu", "role" => "new developer"}, path_info: ["animal"], path_params: %{}, port: 4000, private: %{InvestmentBackWeb.Router => {[], %{Plug.Swoosh.MailboxPreview => ["mailbox"]}}, :before_send => [#Function<0.11807388/1 in Plug.Telemetry.call/2>, #Function<1.86886788/1 in Phoenix.LiveReloader.before_send_inject_reloader/3>], :phoenix_action => :create, :phoenix_controller => InvestmentBackWeb.AnimalController, :phoenix_endpoint => InvestmentBackWeb.Endpoint, :phoenix_format => "json", :phoenix_layout => {InvestmentBackWeb.LayoutView, :app}, :phoenix_request_logger => {"request_logger", "request_logger"}, :phoenix_router => InvestmentBackWeb.Router, :phoenix_view => InvestmentBackWeb.AnimalView, :plug_session_fetch => #Function<1.84243074/1 in Plug.Session.fetch_session/1>}, query_params: %{}, query_string: "", remote_ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, req_cookies: %{}, req_headers: [{"accept", "*/*"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}, {"content-length", "118"}, {"content-type", "application/json"}, {"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"postman-token", "5528ed3e-d8de-4e2e-82e3-2d7b1b3bde39"}, {"user-agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.31.3"}], request_path: "/animal", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}, {"x-request-id", "F0-VSsiF-LxMK_gAAAAC"}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: :..., state: :unset, status: nil}

    # 2
    %{"address" => "china", "email" => "smallstul@gmail.com", "name" => "xingxingliu", "role" => "new developer"}
```

I don't why problem appear. I will be greatly appreciated someone points out.

the elixir version:

```
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [jit] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.14.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 25)
```

the phoenix version is 1.6.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated Phoenix Controller expects the Animal data to be inside the key `"animal"`, not at the top level. You can fix this by modifying your Postman request to have the body like this:

```json
{
  "animal": {
    "name": "something",
    "email": "...",
    ...
  }
}
```